# Testing all files in a directory with a program

Tags: shell, command-line

I have a parser **myParser** which can read a file using < e.g. if I am to parse a file a.txt, I simply type

```
$ myParser < a.txt
```

I have many such files in a directory which itself contain many other directories. For example

```
dir1
|- dir12
|   |- a.txt
|   |- b.txt
|- dir2
|   |- dir21
|   |    |-dir31
|   |    |    |-c.txt
```

I want to run a single command which can parse all these *.txt file for me.

Any suggestion while I play around with {find -exec}.

UPDATE : doing `$ find ./ iname "*.txt" -exec ./Bin/myParser {} \;`gives `./Bin/myParser permission denied`.

Comment: does Bin/myParser has executable permission

Comment: yes. It is working fine when I use on a single file. Checked it now. Permission and ownership of all files are fine.

Comment: But you are using 'myParser' on your first example, and './Bin/myParser' on the second. I doubt they are the same if your own example worked, and that solution didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find  <root_dir_name> -name *.txt | xargs myParser
```

Comment: ./Bin/BlueSpec: 1: //: Permission denied
./Bin/BlueSpec: 3: //: Permission denied
./Bin/BlueSpec: 4: //: Permission denied
./Bin/BlueSpec: 5: //: Permission denied
./Bin/BlueSpec: 6: //: Permission denied
./Bin/BlueSpec: 7: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")") where BlueSpec is myParser

Comment: root dir means that where your all test txt file. if you are giving / it will scan full file system.

Comment: I gave ./ as <root_dir_name> . It is returning relative path. That is fine.

Comment: . will be enough. and run command as sudo, if you don't have permission on files.

Comment: By the way. Replacing myParser with cat works fine. It displays the contents of all fine. And sudo does not solve any problem. :-(

Comment: You probably want `-name '*.txt'`, there might be `.txt` files in the current directory and you don't want the shell expanding the wildcard.

Comment: Working now. Thanks! I had to recompile the binary.